# Trying to do a Core Data migration of a single attribute of an entity in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

I am working on an iOS application that requires Heavy Weight Migration of a single attribute of an entity.  The attribute is of type Integer16 in the original Data Model schema, and I need to change the type to a String in the new schema.  The relationships that exist in the original model will remain the same in the new model.

This is the first time I'm doing a heavy weight migration, and thankfully its not a very complex one but unfortunately I am very unsure as to how to do this.  I have created a MappingModel, and in turn, I've also created a subclass of NSEntityMigrationPolicy which is referenced from the mapping model that I've created.  I realize that I need to override the method: createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance in this subclass, which I am trying to do as follows:

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {

    NSLog(@"boo");
    NSManagedObjectContext *destMOC = [manager destinationContext];
    NSString *destEntityName = [mapping destinationEntityName];
    NSString *name = [sInstance valueForKey:@"zip"];

    return YES;
}
```

After running my project, the values for the attribute that already exist in my application come out to (null) which is not surprising, and the above output appears in the console as many times as there are records that need to be migrated over.  However, how would I now convert the attribute from Integer16 to String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bit of sample code for the `createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance`. Basically you loop over the attributes and modify the value of the attribute(s) of interest. Attributes that do not require change are simply copied across.

The actual conversion from the old value (int) to the new value (string) should be placed where is says `here do conversion as needed`.

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)inSourceInstance
                                 entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)inMapping
      manager:(NSMigrationManager *)inManager
                                         error:(NSError **)outError {
    NSManagedObject *newObject;
    NSEntityDescription *sourceInstanceEntity = [inSourceInstance entity];

    // correct entity? just to be sure
    if ( [[sourceInstanceEntity name] isEqualToString:@"<-the_entity->"] ) { 
        newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"<-the_entity->" inManagedObjectContext:[inManager destinationContext]];

        // obtain the attributes
        NSDictionary *keyValDict = [inSourceInstance committedValuesForKeys:nil];
        NSArray *allKeys = [[[inSourceInstance entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
        // loop over the attributes
        for (NSString *key  in allKeys) {
              // Get key and value
              id value = [keyValDict objectForKey:key];
              if ( [key isEqualToString:@"<-the_attribute->"] ) {
                 // === here retrieve old value ==
                 id oldValue = [keyValDict objectForKey:key];
                 // === here do conversion as needed ==
                 // === then store new value ==
                 [newObject setValue:@"<-the_converted_string->" forKey:key];
              } else { // no need to modify the value. Copy it across
                 [newObject setValue:value forKey:key];
              }
        }

    [inManager associateSourceInstance:inSourceInstance  withDestinationInstance:newObject forEntityMapping:inMapping];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Olaf for your detailed solution.  This really helps me on my way!

Answer (score 0):

In your method, you are calling some getters from `NSMigrationManager` and `NSEntityMapping` and you store these values in local variables that get discarded once the method finishes.

What exactly did you expect it to do apart from `NSLog(@"boo");`?

Comment: I need to know how to do the conversion, which is what I am unsure of.  I only included the NSLog statement just to confirm that I was reaching the method when I ran the application.